# Duvida com variáveis e exibir na lista com PHP

Tags: php, html5

Queria saber como eu poderia exibir estes dados:

```
<?php 
// session_start();
include("conexao.php");//chama o arquivo que faz a conexão com o banco 
 $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from usuarios order by nome asc");//"joga" a query na variavel sql

 //a variavel exibe é para exibir os dados da lista do banco
 while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){

 echo $exibe["id"];
 echo $exibe["nome"];
 echo $exibe["email"];
 echo $exibe["senha"];
 echo $exibe["telefone"];

 }
?>
```

Que estão sendo exibidos com echo para uma lista no html5:

```
<form method="POST"action="lista.php">
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
      <th scope="col">Telefone</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>     
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Fiz o teste com echo para ver se funcionaria e sim eu consigo puxar os itens do meu banco de dados, no caso, phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 4):

Se entendi corretamente você quer exibir os dados retornados do banco na sua tabela em `html`, então acho que o código abaixo pode te ajudar.

```
<?php 
//chama o arquivo que faz a conexão com o banco 
include("conexao.php");

//"joga" a query na variavel sql
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from usuarios order by nome asc");
?>

<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
      <th scope="col">Telefone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <?php while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)): ?>
      <tr>
          <th scope="row"><?php echo $data["id"]; ?></th>
          <td><?php echo $data["nome"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data["email"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $data["telefone"]; ?></td>
      </tr>     
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: faltou abrir o while Kayo

Comment: Verdade, obrigado @gmsantos.

Comment: Desculpe mas não entendi o porque da variável $data ? ela foi criada naquele momento para que ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\testephp\listaPage.php on line 93

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\testephp\listaPage.php on line 93 Aparece essas linhas quando tento executar o projeto depois de colocar o seu codigo @KayoBruno

Comment: @MarceloL, esse é só o nome escolhido pra capturar o retorno, em vez de `$data` poderia continuar sendo a que vc criou, `$exibe` sem problemas

Comment: @MarceloL, sobre o erro, verifica se vc possui essa linha de consulta do banco (select *...) com esse nome de variável, `$sql`

Comment: $result_usuarios = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$resultado_usuarios = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuarios);
esse é o meu "lista.php" aonde eu faço a conexão com o banco e chamo ele no começo da lista

Comment: @DimasPante esqueci de marcar kkk

Comment: @MarceloL, tranquilo. Então, é só vc trocar a variável dentro que mysqli_fetch_assoc, de `$sql`pra `$result_usuarios`

Comment: @DimasPante ai que ta...ja testei e da isso aqui Notice: Undefined variable: result_usuarios in C:\xampp\htdocs\testephp\listaPage.php on line 106

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98326/discussion-between-dimas-pante-and-marcelo-l).